# Suscripción a un observable en método get de HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, observable

Estoy aprendiendo Angular y el curso está un poco desactualizado, resulta que estoy creando una aplicación muy simple en la cual se muestra un listado de personas, creadas a partir de una clase `Persona` que recibe los parámetros `nombre` y `apellido`.

El código es el siguiente:

data.services.ts:

```
    cargarPersonas(){
        return this.httpClient.get('https://listado-personas-53faf-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/personas.json');
    }

    guardarPersonas(personas: Persona[]){
        this.httpClient.put('https://listado-personas-53faf-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/personas.json', personas).subscribe(
            response => alert(`Datos enviados correctamente: ${response}`),
            error => alert(`Error al enviar los datos: ${error}`)
        );
    }
```

persona.service.ts:

```
  setPersonas(personas: Persona[]){
    this.personas = personas;
  }

  obtenerPersonas(){
    return this.dataService.cargarPersonas();
  }

  agregarPersona(persona: Persona) {
    this.logginService.enviarMensajeAConsola('agregamos persona:' + persona.nombre);
    if(this.personas == null){
      this.personas = [];
    }
    this.personas.push(persona);
    this.dataService.guardarPersonas(this.personas);
  }
```

personas.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.personasService.obtenerPersonas().subscribe(
      (personas: Persona[]) => {
        this.personas = personas;
        this.personasService.setPersonas(personas);
      }
    );
  }
```

Al realizar esto recibo el error `Ninguna sobrecarga coincide con esta llamada`. Investigando un poco encontré que debía modificar la suscripción en personas.component.ts de la siguiente manera:

```
this.personasService.obtenerPersonas().subscribe(
      (personas: Object) => {
        this.personas = personas as Persona[];
        this.personasService.setPersonas(personas as Persona[]);
      }
    );
```

Esto solucionó el error anterior, sin embargo recibo el error `NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`.

Cuando realizo un `console.log()` de el objeto que recibo al suscribirme (`personas`) puedo ver que es un objeto que contiene un arreglo pero no se como puedo hacer para acceder a dicho arreglo ya que si intento iterarlo también recibo error, con `Object.keys(personas)` recibo una cadena con el nombre de la llave y con `Object.values(personas)` recibo otro objeto.

¿Cómo puedo lograr trabajar con el array de objetos tipo Persona que recibo desde firebase?

EDIT:

Cuando realizo un `console.log()` de el objeto que recibo al suscribirme (`personas`) me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: console.log(personas)]

Comment: Que te tira si pones `this.personasService.obtenerPersonas().subscribe(
      (personas: Object) => {
       console.log(personas)
      }
    );`

Comment: @Yussef Te lo adjunto en una imagen en un edit del post, ahí tengo sólo un objeto del tipo Persona registrado en la DB. Si agrego más aparecen con su ID al igual que el que muestro con índice 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, lograron explicarme el motivo por el cual recibía el error. El problema era que el método `cargarPersonas()` no estaba retornando un objeto `Observable<Persona[]>`, sino que retornaba un objeto HTTP Response. De esta manera, para poder recibir el objeto deseado, debí modificar el método dejándolo de la siguiente manera:

```
    cargarPersonas(){
            return this.httpClient.get<Persona[]>('https://listado-personas-53faf-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/personas.json');
        }
```

Acá hay más información al repecto: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response